# Не могу поменять id у элемента в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-studio

Создал Activity используя new-> Activity-> Empty Activity
добавляю в ConstraintLayout элемент Plain Text, по умолчанию id у него editTextTextPersonName
Меняю его на editTextHouse, появляется окно "Rename", нажимаю Refactor, при этом ни каких ошибок нет.
Но id у элемента по прежнему editTextTextPersonName

Comment: Зайдите в верстку и поменяйте ручками

Comment: хотелось бы понять в чем проблема

Comment: Возможно, Вы что-то не то нажимаете, может галочку какую-нибудь неправильно выставляете. Без живого контакта тут хрен разберешься - надо видеть, что вы делаете